# LWC Display dynamicly queried fields in lwc html

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a dynamicly created record in LWC.js like this:

[
{
“Id”: “00Q0D000006GAAJUA4",
“Name”: “Jane Doe”,
“FieldXYZ__c”: “Plane”,
“FIELDABC__c”: “Seat”,
“FIELDZUI__c”: “Instagram”,
“FIELDUUUN__c”: “Easy Contract”
}
]

Dynamicly means, which fields are queried is setup by MetaDataTypes. So it can be different fields and I cannot code them fix into the HTML Template.
How would I display this in the LWC HTML Template with in an iteration, when I cannot fix code the fields?

normaly I would display them this way:

```
<template for:each={leads} for:item=“lead”>
  <div key={lead.Id} class=“card” data-id={lead.Id} onclick={handleClick}>
    <div class=“group” data-id={lead.Id}>{lead.Name}</div>
    <div class=“item” data-id={lead.Id}>FieldXYZ: {lead.FieldXYZ__c}</div>
    <div class=“item” data-id={lead.Id}>FIELDABC: {lead.FIELDABC__c}</div>
    <div class=“item” data-id={lead.Id}>FIELDZUI: {lead.FIELDZUI__c}</div>
    <div class=“item” data-id={lead.Id}>FIELDUUUN: {lead.FIELDUUUN__c}</div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Can I iterate over the delivered fields and how?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only iterate over `Array`s, not `Object`s. There's no such thing as "dynamic" access in LWC.

This is usually pretty trivial. First, map out the data how you want it laid out.

```
this.leads = this.leads.map((lead) => ({
  Id: lead.Id,
  Name: lead.Name,
  values: Object.entries(lead)
    .filter((field) => field[0] !== "Id" && field[0] !== "Name")
    .map(([fieldName, value]) => ({
      fieldName,
      value,
    })),
}));
```

Which makes your template:

```
<div for:each={leads} 
     for:item="lead" 
     key={lead.Id} 
     class="card" 
     data-id={lead.Id} 
     onclick={handleClick}>
  <div class="group" 
       data-id={lead.Id}>
    {lead.Name}
  </div>
  <div class="item" 
       data-id={lead.Id} 
       for:each={lead.values} 
       for:item="fieldValue" 
       key={fieldValue.fieldName}>
    {fieldValue.fieldName}: {fieldValue.value}
  </div>
</div>
```